# When is the ideal generated by 2 elements equal to the sum of the 2 ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is it true in general that (a,b)=(a)+(b)?
I would suppose that (a)+(b)$\subset$(a,b) and i believe the reverse containment should hold as well, i just can't seem to fit the pieces together.

Comment: This is true more or less by definition. Both are the intersection of all ideals containing both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Basically the same as the above comment, but $(a,b)$ is the smallest ideal containing both $a$ and $b$.  Since $a$ and $b$ are in $(a) + (b)$ which is an ideal, that shows $(a,b)\subset (a) + (b)$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting variables and signs in future questions.

Comment: You can (maybe more handy and concrete for beginners, though its not that sophisticated) also use the elementwise definitions of $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ and $I+J$ to see that both ideals in the question are equal.